# CS50 Runoff - why does the 'strcmp() function' in my code actually work?

Tags: c, cs50

Although I have successfully completed the vote function part of the exercise `bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)` I don't really see how the computer passes the code line:  `if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)` as correct in the vote function below.

For example, suppose you enter 3 candidates as `argv`'s. `"dim", "oli" & "mat"` in this order. Voter 0 chooses `'mat dim oli'` as his preferences in the `// Keep querying for votes` section of `int main`.

How is it possible then that `if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)` is correct?

Because in the first loop, `i = 0`, `candidates[i].name` is equal to `"dim"` (`argv [0 + 1]`) but the first voter chooses `"mat"` as his first preference (rank 0) which is actually (`argv [2 + 1]`) which doesn't match with `"dim"` (`argv [0 + 1]`), isn't it?

Maybe a step by step explanation of how the loops work in this case would help.

```
// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
 
    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    
    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        **if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)**
        {
        preferences[voter][rank] = i;
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That just looks through the array of candidates for one that has a matching name. If it finds a match it records a vote and stops iterating. What's with all the `+1` stuff in your explanation? C arrays are zero indexed.

Comment: Please don't forget the *minimal* part of your [mcve]. It's very hard to find the single statement you're asking about.

Comment: Use a debugger and execute yourt code step by step. Or at least put some printfs at strategic points in your code so you can see what's going on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I've cut down the code relevant to my question only. Is it clearer now? Still learning to work with SF. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @tadman now it makes sense, thank you. With the +1 I was just referring to candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1]; when inputting i = 0, i = 1,... as in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `strcmp`'s return value as "differences", where 0 means "no difference" or in other words, a match. If you're ever stumped your first stop should be [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) as that's how we all find out about how things are supposed to work.

In other words `strcmp("dim","dim")` will be `0`.

Comment: This is why I often like to do `#define streq !strcmp`, removes a lot of the confusion

Comment: @joH1 Please don't. Just use `strcmp` and don't invent your own C dialect nobody can understand. It may be a little confusing at first, but you get used to it fast.

Comment: @joH1 ...and replaces it with your personal secret macro language, not confusing at all.

Comment: @joH1: The only problem with your macro definition is it is non-grammatical, so substituting it might produce unexpected results in some circumstances. If you instead define it as `#define streq(a, b) (!strcmp((a), (b))`, then it is a function-like macro. Ignore the complaints about inventing your own dialect/language. People write subroutines all the time, and defining the macro this way fits into that paradigm just fine.

Comment: Well I only use it in my own code, and since `!` has precedence over any other operator that will made sense to use it's safe. I'm just using it in `if` statements anyway, where I find it to convey more clearly the intent.

Comment: @tadman your first comment under my question was actually the answer I was looking for. As regards your answer re strcmp is also useful, for which thanks. If you want to add your first comment in the answer section feel free to. Either way I accept the answer. Thanks, grateful.